# Python selenium find element by background gradient

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, background

Previously I find elements like this:

```
element = fox.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'well')]/p[2]/a[@style='background:#0373F1;']")
```

It works well! But now element has a gradient:

```
"background:transparent linear-gradient(to bottom, #31A61A 0%, #217510 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0%"
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: If the background color changes now and then, you might be better off finding the element by ID or class rather than the style attribute.

Comment: Background color do not change and its immposible to find element by class name or id.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below xpath. It should work

```
element = fox.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'well')]/p[2]/a[contains(@style,'background:transparent linear-gradient')]")
```

Comment: There are others elements like this one have colors another one gradient and this only diference beetwen them.Your path work but it clicked all of them but I need only with gradient.